# How can I change the row height of cross table in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I try to change row height(Not Header) of cross table in Spotfire.
This ↓ is my Iron Python script code.(Here I try to change the first row's height as to 50). But it gives me an error.

***from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import CrossTablePlot***

vis.AsCrossTablePlot.CellHeight[0]=50

Any Idea?

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CellHeight property of the cross table is an integer, not an array or list. This means you can't actually access specific rows with indexing (or any other way). The api also does not differentiate between header row and data rows when setting this property. This will set the row heights, but the header will be included.

If the row heights are manually changed, the row headers are no longer included in the resizing through the ironpython. This, I suppose, must remain a mystery.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import CrossTablePlot

vis.As[CrossTablePlot]().CellHeight=50
```